# How the observed deuterium abundance constrains big bang nucleosynthesis?

Tags: galaxy, cosmology, big-bang-theory, observational-astronomy, nucleosynthesis

I know deuterium can be used as a good tracer to constrain the big bang nucleosynthesis. But can anyone tell me the in details how this is actually done?

Comment: [Does the wikipedia entry on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang_nucleosynthesis#Deuterium) give what you need?